# OnClickListener on dynamic table layout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I want to add onClicklistener to the items from the dynamic table that is generated.
My Code is

```
for(int k=0;k<i;k++)        
{

    tr[k]=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    tr[k].layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
        ids[k] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        ids[k].setText(loc_id[k]);
        ids[k].setPadding(30, 15, 30, 15);
        loc[k] = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        loc[k].setText(loc_name[k]);      
        loc[k].setPadding(30, 15, 30    ,15);
        tr[k].setPadding(0, 1, 0, 0);   
        tr[k].addView(ids[k]);
        tr[k].addView(loc[k]);
      tl.addView(tr[k], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to add `OnClickListner` Interface to your activity and then add all dynamic view to `setOnClickListner` and finally you can catch click event for all view inside `onClick(View view)` method.

Comment: need onclick on both textview or only one ..??

Comment: On clicking the row,I want to get the value of id[k] .. Please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add **OnClickListner Interface** to your activity and then add all dynamic view to **setOnClickListner** and finally you can catch click event for all view inside **onClick(View view)** method.

Try this

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

int i = 10; // input no of row

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // set here your layout xml name 

    //TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(MainScreen.this);
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainScreen.this);
        tr.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
        TextView ids = new TextView(MainScreen.this);
        ids.setText(loc_id[k]);
        ids.setPadding(30, 15, 30, 15);
        TextView loc = new TextView(MainScreen.this);
        loc.setText(loc_name[k]);
        loc.setPadding(30, 15, 30, 15);
        tr.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 0);
        tr.addView(ids);
        tr.addView(loc);
        tr.setId(k); // here you can set unique id to TableRow for
                        // identification
        tr.setOnClickListener(MainScreen.this); // set TableRow onClickListner
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }

    //setContentView(tl);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int clicked_id = v.getId(); // here you get id for clicked TableRow

    // now you can get value like this

    String ids = loc_id[clicked_id];
    String loc = loc_name[clicked_id];

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but sorry I forget to mention I use this function inside the new CountDownTimer function onfinish method,So the above code doesnt works :( shows error .

Comment: I think that's `Context` problem so please replace `this` with `ActivityNAme.this`.

Comment: yeah It works :) Thanks alot.But scroll option is missing.Can we add scroll option ?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/walb"
    android:clickable="true">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:id="@+id/table"
       android:background="@drawable/walb"
       android:stretchColumns="0,1">
 </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>`


But Scroll View is not working :(

Comment: you need to Initialize TableLayout like this `TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);` and also setContentView with your xml file see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks alot :) it works, Another case..I have a button Edit and delete at Action Bar, Clicking the Edit button want to change the  clicked `TextView` to `EditText` and Clicking Delete will remove clicked  ids,and loc from the list.How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sukan: Sorry to say but i never work with Action Bar...so no idea about Action Bar..:(

Comment: its ok.. Consider two Buttons Edit and Delete in a switch case (Menu Bar case)...Clicking Edit will change the Clicked `Textview` to `EditText` and Clicking delete will remove the ids and loc of clicked row.

Comment: Tiger: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754067/menubar-item-tablelayout-dynamically-onclicklistener

Comment: i think you need to add TextView and EditText (Initialy InVisible)to TableRow.Then when you press Edit But Visible EditText and Invisible TextView After EditText complt editing you may visible textview and invisile edittext..

Comment: How can I add ViewSwitcher(Textview and EditText) in my tablelayout ?

Comment: Refer [example-of-viewswitcher](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/11/example-of-viewswitcher.html) and [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).

Comment: check the below answer,where I used another approach, there I hope u'll help me @BlackTiger:

Comment: Hi :) how to add a header to the above table ?

Comment: You may add one dummy tableraw above for loop and add this raw to tablelayout also.... I hope you will get idea

Comment: TableRow tr1Row=new TableRow(MapID.this);
    TextView head=new TextView(MapID.this);
    head.setText("xxxx");
    tr1Row.addView(head);
    
       for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {


is this?

Comment: Yes, now also add tr1row to table layout...if not working tell me